# Can't get c3.js right click event arguments

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'd like to control right click event on c3.js graphs.
I found a solution [Right mouse click detection on SVG shape in JavaScript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421072/how-to-add-update-c3-charts-to-listen-for-a-right-click-mouse-event),
but I can't get data and index arguments.
Is there any solution?

Libraries I use are as follows.
c3.js v0.7.18
d3.js v5.16.0
I also use firebase js plugins.

```
onrendered: function () {
  d3.select("#chart1")
    .selectAll(".c3-event-rect")
    .on("contextmenu", function (d,i) {
      console.log(d); //argument d is always undefined.
      console.log(i); //argument i is always 0.
      d3.event.preventDefault(); // prevent default menu
      var vals = Chart1.data().map(function (series) {
        var name = series.id;
        return { name: name };
        //value: Chart1.data.values(name)[d.x]}; // d.x is the index
      });
    alert ("data: "+JSON.stringify(vals));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeh, that was my solution you reference, but unfortunately it looks like they've updated c3 so there's now only one .c3-event-rect per chart rather than per x-axis point so there's no d and i info attached

Probably your best hope is to add a feature request to the c3 github repository asking for a specific right-click listener